# Установка 32 разрядной LabVIEW на Linux c с поддержкой VISA

Tags: linux

Всем привет.
Собственно интересует пошаговая инструкция по установке.
Архитектура PC позволяет.
У меня 2 версии LabView 14 и 18.

Comment: дистрибутив какой?

Comment: @eri, гораздо интереснее было бы узнать, что такое «c с поддержкой VISA».

Comment: NI-VISA is an API that provides a programming interface to control Ethernet/LXI, GPIB, serial, USB, PXI, and VXI instruments in National Instruments application development environments

@aleksandrbarakin кто в теме лабвью, элвисов и прочего - тот знает)

Comment: @eri, спасибо за разъяснение. а то я уже грешным делом подумал, что торвальдс решил на платёжных системах побарыжить.

Comment: @eri, ну я не в теме, однако в курсе про это. Как-то зацепило немного на работе, в одном проекте нужна была небольшая помощь...

Comment: А чё именно не пашет?

Comment: Есть потребность перевести проект на Linux. Все должно, обязано пахать, я с Linux особо раньше не работал. Установил ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop, а дальше тьма непоняток. Если в.у. туториала нет, кстати у NI его нет, то путь непростой.